# Transparent Overlay Creating PNG

Tags: php, image, transparency, gd

I have the below function and I've gotten it to the size I need, now I'm adding a background image and then looking to add just text overlay with a transparent background on all the overlay text but `imagefilledrectangle` applies the variable `$white` which is expected, I'm trying to see if there is anyway to tell the function to be transparent instead of accepting a colour, white in this instance, the PHP docs say that the colour is a required parameter for `imagefilledrectangle`, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

The background image is a local image:

```
define("BACKGROUND_FILE", "background.png");
```

Function:

```
public function generateImage()
{
    if (file_exists(BACKGROUND_FILE)) {     
        $im = @imagecreatefrompng(BACKGROUND_FILE);

        if($im) {
            $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 115, 150, 195);

            imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

            $text = 'Test';
            $font = 'arial_narrow_7.ttf';

            imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding `imagecolortransparent($im, $white);` before `imagefilledrectangle` but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, there is no need to have the `imagefilledrectangle` line in the function, the below gives transparent overlay text elements as no fill is now being applied.

```
public function generateImage()
{
    if (file_exists(BACKGROUND_FILE)) {     
        $im = @imagecreatefrompng(BACKGROUND_FILE);

        if($im) {
            $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 115, 150, 195);

            $text = 'Test';
            $font = 'arial_narrow_7.ttf';

            imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
}
```